# Flutter: Google cloud storage not giving me access despite my rules

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have looked through every tutorial and the steps in retrieving the directories are more or less the same however I hit a snag and there doesn't seem to be anyone encountering this. So in my application, I have a button that calls a function

```
 onPressed: () async {
                        isListing
                            ? _showMyDialog()
                            : setState(() {
                                isListing = !isListing;
                              });
                        try {
                          directories=await firebaseAPI.list(
                              '${widget.level}/${widget.value}');
                          setState(() {

                            isListing = !isListing;
                            prefs.setBool('isInitialized', true);
                          });
                          _showNotification();
                          prefs.setBool('isInitialized', true);
                          Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                              context, Dashboard.id, (route) => false);
                        } catch (error) {}
                      }
```

And here's the code for the list function

```
    Future<firebase_storage.ListResult> downloadFiles(url) async {
final ref =
        firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(url);
    final result = await ref.listAll();
    print(result);

    return result;
}
```

The function gets called but doesn't print or return anything it just gives me this:

```
W/NetworkRequest(13843): no auth token for request
W/StorageUtil(13843): no auth token for request
W/NetworkRequest(13843): No App Check token for request.
```

Which I don't get since I changed my rules to this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, allow write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Do I have to change the rules further? or is there a different way of accessing google cloud storage?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just did a cold boot of my emulator and now it's able to access it

Comment: Good to hear you got it working .    I flagged your questions as being ephemeral/not reproducible, as it is unlikely that somebody who is in the caught in the same situation will ever find it.

Answer (score -1):

Firestore storage needs authentication in order to upload data,  so you need to use firebase_auth or you need to change the rules to: `allow read, write;`

Comment: Still prints the same thing